# Query that fails ONLY when one table is empty

Tags: mysql

So I need to do join on a table. This is the query I use:

```
SELECT CONCAT(u.Apellido, ', ', u.Nombre) AS Nombre, u.keyid AS keyid 
FROM tUsuarios AS u, tLaboratorio AS l 
WHERE (l.Responsable != u.keyid) AND (u.Activo = '1' AND u.keyid != -1)
```

I need all the users for the table tUsuarios whose unique identifier is NOT in any of the rows in the column Responsable found in Table l (hence the u.keyid != l.Responsable)

If there is at least one entry in tLaboratorio this works. Otherwise it returns an empty set. However, that table WILL be empty when the system is used for the first time.

The only solution that I can think of is to test if the tLaboratorio is empty and do an entirely different query in that case. Is there a way to fix the query so that it will work on both cases?

Comment: Correct your SQL to use proper JOIN syntax, make it a LEFT JOIN, and you can check for the tLaboratorio column being NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to join the tables. You only need a simple nested query.

```
SELECT CONCAT(u.Apellido, ', ', u.Nombre) AS Nombre, u.keyid AS keyid 
FROM tUsuarios AS u 
WHERE u.keyid NOT IN (SELECT Responsable FROM tLaboratorio) AND u.Activo = '1' AND u.keyid != -1
```